# Why are all my slides visible at the same time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I implemented a very basic slideshow by toggling the visibility of the current slide and the next slide to go from one to the other. Eventually, I will replace this simple `toggle()`
by a fancy animation with `toggle('slide', {easing: 'easeInOutCirc'}, 'slow');`, but that will have to wait until I get [a few bugs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8441726/how-can-only-certain-jquery-ui-toggle-effects-work-where-others-fail) out of the way. Anyways, the slideshow works fine as is, but it breaks when I do the following

**Reproducing the bug**:

1. Make sure javascript is enabled on your browser
2. Go to [shawninder.99k.org/index.php](http://shawninder.99k.org/index.php)
3. Click on any language on the right hand side. This will show a little description under the language and filter the jobs list to show only those during which I've used that language.
4. Click on that same language again to close it.
5. Now click on "Database Administrator & Software Consultant". It will open up and you will see a picture, a bunch of quotes with signatures, and a paragraph
6. **Problem:** Only one of these quotes should show up at first. In fact, if you reload the page and click directly on the job without clicking on a language first, the slideshow works as intended!

I would appreciate any advice on how to debug this kind of problem.

Feel free to have a look at [the javascript file](http://shawninder.99k.org/js/myScripts.js)

Thanks a lot in advance!

PS I'm still in the development phase and I've only tested the site in chromium-browser on ubuntu 11.10.